# Time Series Chart not working with TimePeriod="Month"

Tags: charts, jasper-reports, timeserieschart

I have created a time series chart in Jaspersoft studio. It works fine when I set TimePeriod="Day", but chart is empty when TimePeriod="Month". Data is created in java backend app, and passed with JRBeanCollectionDataSource :

```
Map<String, Object> statsModel = new HashMap<>();
statsModel.put("interval", date);
statsModel.put("accepted", accepted);
statsModel.put("rejected", rejected);
statsModel.put("unresolved", unresolved);

Collection statsList = new LinkedList();
statsList.add(statsModel);
JRBeanCollectionDataSource reportData = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(statsList);
```

date: java.util.Date in format "yyyy-MM-dd", theres exactly one value per each day in interval.

accepted, rejected, resolved: long

Shouldn't TimePeriod="Month" make jasper to add all the values of the month and show it on the chart?

Comment: Any success with your case?

Comment: I did not find any Jaspersoft solution. I had to calculate for each month and pass it to jasper

Comment: Hi could you please post your .jrxml file? The part containing the chart code.